# How can I cancel an appointment in outlook if someone cancels it?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have many 1:1 meetings. If the other person cancels the invite I want to delete the whole appointment. It seems to me that I have to go into the canendar and FIND the specific date and appointment and delete it from there. Is there a way to jump from the cancellation straight to the appointment to cancel it?

Comment: What have you found in your research so far?

Comment: As I described, there seems to be no way to go to or open the appointment from the invite-rejection.

Comment: I looked too. There doesn't seem to be a way to do it as you described.